# How can I distribute msvr71.dll (microsoft visual c++ runtime dll)

Tags: visual-c++, licensing, msvcrt, redistributable, visual-c++-runtime

I have an application that requires msvcr71.dll. In some machines the DLL is missing. Instead of asking the user to install the VC++ runtime, I would like to distribute the DLL (only one file msvcr71.dll) with our application. This gets  copied to application installation directory.

From a licensing point of view, am I doing it correct?  I could not find any license agreement.

The [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326922) has following note:

> For Msvcr70.dll or for Msvcr71.dll, you should install the CRT DLL into your application program files directory. You should not install these files into the Windows system directories. For Msvcr80.dll and for Msvcr90.dll, you should install the CRT as Windows side-by-side assemblies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a `redist.txt` file in `Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003` that states the rules for redistributing different files from Visual Studio.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984372.aspx has another list of locations to check for `redist.txt`.

Comment: how can I download msvcr71.dll without install VS 2003 ?